# create a home simulator using HTML 5 CANVAS API

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas

It's possible to create a design simulator like this one bellow using Canvas?
http://www.carreaux-granito.com/simulateur-carreaux-granito-personalises.php#

Comment: that one is totally bugged in Chrome... Also the answer is YES. Also you should not ask such questions here on SO, as you have read before asking your question. Refer to [help]

Answer (score 0):

Similar work has been done on the subject check out 
keithclark's work out of the uk
http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/creating-3d-worlds-with-html-and-css/

Now even many game engines support HTML5 for open gl 
like my favorite dev kit UnrealEngine 4 from epic 
[Getting Started: Developing HTML5 Projects | Unreal Engine](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Platforms/HTML5/GettingStarted/)

Comment: Since you have link-only help for the questioner, please put your helpful links in a comment to the question rather than posting it as an answer. This is because Stackoverflow encourages answers to not rely on links that may "rot". Thanks ;-)